# Como enviar parametros de index.php a .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Buen día.

Estoy realizando el envió de datos de .htaccess a un archivo en php, lo hago por medio de la url y funciona perfecto, pero como puedo enviarlos desde un index.php al htaccess por parametros.

HTML

```
 <form action="" method="">
    <input type="text" name="peticion" placeholder="Cuenta">
    <input type="password" name="opcion" placeholder="Clave">
    <input type="password" name="parte" placeholder="Clave">
    <input type="submit"  value="Enviar">
    </form>
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+) ../Recibe.php?peticion=$1&opcion=$2&parte=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes enviar parámetros a .htacces, porque es un archivo interpretado por el servidor web (Apache) y, lo que realmente debes hacer, es crear una URL que pueda ser interpretada por Mod_Rewrite, entonces, tal vez debas usar javascript para crear esa URL:

```js
let formRedir = document.querySelector('#form-redir');
// Crear URL cuando el formulario sea enviado
formRedir.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    let peticion = document.querySelector('[name="peticion"]').value.trim();
    let opcion = document.querySelector('[name="opcion"]').value.trim();
    let parte = document.querySelector('[name="parte"]').value.trim();
    // Revisar que no haya campos vacíos
    if(peticion == '' || opcion == '' || parte == '') {
        // No procesar el formulario
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        // Agregar partes a la acción del formulario
        this.action += `${peticion}/${opcion}/${parte}/`;
        console.log(this.action);
        // Elimina o comenta la siguiente línea para que se pueda procesar
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
    <form action="http://tudominio.com" method="get" id="form-redir">
    <input type="text" name="peticion" placeholder="Cuenta">
    <input type="password" name="opcion" placeholder="Clave">
    <input type="password" name="parte" placeholder="Clave">
    <input type="submit"  value="Enviar">
    </form>
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono perfecto